# outlook-web-addin - Outlook calendar event start/end property depends on the selected timezone?

Tags: timezone, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am building an outlook addin which is active during compose/edit of an outlook calendar event. The addin accesses the start/end time of the event with the apis described 
[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.1/office.context.mailbox.item#start-datetimejavascriptapioutlook11officetime). This yields a Time object, described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook_1_1/office.time?view=office-js), on which I use getAsync() to get a Date object.

According to my interpretation of the documentation about the [start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.1/office.context.mailbox.item#start-datetimejavascriptapioutlook11officetime) property, the "result" argument of the callback called by [getAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook_1_1/office.time?view=office-js#getasync-options--callback-) should be a time expressed as UTC, but this is not the case (it is expressed in local time).

But this, as far as I understand, is a javascript Date peculiarity, and I can handle it. The real problem I have is that outlook 365 allows to select a timezone in the event creation form, as can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRhXs.png).
When I change the timezone, accessing the start property from the addin results in a different time (which is also expressed in local time). I would expect the same time (as before selecting a different timezone). Looking at the event created by Outlook in the calendar, it is also clear that Outlook does know it is the same time, expressed in a different timezone.

So, to make this more concrete:

1. create a new event in the calendar which for example starts at 11:30 and ends at 13:00 (selected timezone in compose form is  local time, for example "Brussels Copenhagen Madrid, UTC + 1")
2. when accessing the start property from the addin, we get a Date object which contains "11:30 UTC + 1" (for a user located in this timezone)
3. now we change the timezone in the form, to "Moscow, St. Petersburg, Volgograd, UTC + 3".
4. when reading the start property, we now get a Date object which contains "13:30 UTC + 1", but we expect the same "10:30 UTC" or maybe "11:30 UTC + 1". The reason we expect this to be the same is that changing the timezone in which the time is expressed should not move the event in time. And actually outlook does not move the event (as can be seen in the calendar), but the start property is telling us that it does.

I'm aware of the Office.context.mailbox.convertUtcClientTime() and Office.context.mailbox.convertToLocalClientTime() methods but, as far as I understand and can test, I can not use those to get what I want.

So my question is: did I misunderstand something or am I doing something wrong, and if so, how do I get the real time at which the event starts/ends (in UTC preferably), but *not* depending on the selected timezone ?

Edit: This behaviour has been observed on Outlook desktop version (version 1901 click-to-run monthly channel, running on windows 10) and also with  Outlook on the web (https://outlook.office365.com/) on multiple web platforms. Our manifest.xml file for the add-in contains the following section

```
<Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
</Hosts>
<Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

The index.html file of the addin contains the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
 src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js"> 
</script>
```

Comment: I had the very same problem. I consider it as a bug, because when changing timezone in Outlook calendar, it does not actually modify the timezone value in JS `Date` object, but adds or subtracts the number of hours in this object. If you find the way to gently solve it, please share it.

Comment: Can you specify that this issue repros for which client - Windows/Mac/Mobile or Web Outlook?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT, All of them. Just create simple Add-in and do: `item.start.getAsync(callback);` and display the date string. Then switch the timezone and see how it works.

Comment: I clarified in the question for what versions of Outlook we have observed this, @Niko is right about how to reproduce it quickly.

Comment: @sergedemarre, you are right that Date displaying in local time is a JavaScript peculiarity. As you noted, the key here is that the Date represents the correct UTC time. We can use .toISOString() to show the UTC time for diagnostics. I need more time to investigate the issue in OWA. At the same time, I want to confirm the behavior you with Windows Outlook desktop.  In Windows Outlook, unlike OWA, changing just the timezone actually moves the meeting time, so change in start.getAsync is expected. If you see otherwise, a screenshot for Windows Outlook would help us understand better.